# Drizzle CacheCall always returns null

Tags: contract-development, truffle, react, drizzle

I have set up drizzle to be able to connect to my smart contract from my react-application. After some fiddling, I decided to make this function in my smart contract:

```
/*** test ***/
uint numberFive = 5;

function getNumber() public view returns (uint) { 
    return numberFive;
}
```

Then I tried to output the number on my page.

```
class Logged extends Component {
  constructor(props, context) {
    super(props);
    this.contracts = context.drizzle.contracts;
    this.methods = this.contracts.ItemOwnership.methods;
    this.numberKey = this.contracts.ItemOwnership.methods.getNumber.cacheCall();

  }

  render() {
    // If the data isn't here yet, show loading
    if(!(this.numberKey in this.props.ItemOwnership.getNumber )) {
      return (
        <h1>Not retrieved yet</h1>
      )
    }
    console.log(this.props.ItemOwnership);
    let number = this.props.ItemOwnership.getNumber[this.numberKey].value;
    return (
      <div>
        <Container className="logged-in">
          <Row>
            <Col className="center">
              <h4>You are logged in to:</h4>
              <h6>{this.props.account} </h6>
              <h1>!{number}!</h1>
              {console.log(number)}
            </Col>
          </Row>
        </Container>
        <br />
      </div>
    )
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    account: state.accounts[0],
    ItemOwnership: state.contracts.ItemOwnership,
  };
};

Logged.contextTypes = {
  drizzle: PropTypes.object,
};
export default drizzleConnect(Logged, mapStateToProps);
```

The test above returns *null*.
However, cacheCall does update the value, as seen in this image of the drizzle store:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Solved. Setting metamask to main net then back to localhost resolved this